# How to change a MongoDB schema property on production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migration

How can I easily change MongoDB documents on a production database? Having a small downtime is not a dealbreaker for me.

I want to change for example from...

```
export const paintingSchema = new Schema({
    design: string,
});
```

to

```
export const paintingSchema = new Schema({
   color: string, // <-- Property name changed here
});
```

I use mongoose and nodejs. Official MongoDB documentation recommends to add a second database and mirror the changes into it. But that seems overkill for my small application. Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by using [$rename](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#_S_rename).

Use this query once to rename the existing documents:

```js
  await Painting.updateMany(
    { design: { $exists: true } }, // filter docs which contains the property
    { $rename: { design: "color" } }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy but the best way to clone the collection first because it is the production as you mentioned.

- first you need to make a new collection (cloned) with the new renamed property

```js
db.CollectionA.aggregate([
    {$addFields: {color: '$design'}},
    {$project: {design: 0}},
    {$out: "CollectionA-new"}
])
```

- then add all your indexes to the new collection
- then make sure the new collection is fine and test it well
- then remove the old collection and rename the new one with the right collection name

```js
db.getCollection('CollectionA-new').renameCollection('CollectionA')
```